# I am trying to compare an item from a tuple and a list but get an error

Tags: python, list, tuples

I just started coding 3 weeks ago for my python game development class. I am trying to compare an item from a tuple and an item from a list and get a response. Whenever I run the code, I get the error that the tuple item is not callable. I will post the code below. Please help me if you know what is wrong. Thank you!

```
pick_up = "Yes"

i = 0

bag = ()

if not bag:
    print("You are empty-handed.")

print("\nYou have found some items")

pick_up = input("\nDo you wish to pick them up? Yes/No")

if pick_up == "Yes":

    print("You have successfully picked up the items!")

    bag = (" Knife ", " Gum ", " Water ",
         " Bandages ", " Toilet Paper ")

    print("\nThese are the items in your bag:")
    print(bag)

if pick_up == "No":
     print("You remain empty handed")

howMany = len(bag)
print ("This is how many items are in your bag:", howMany)

while i < howMany:
    print("\nThis is item:" + str(i) + bag[i])
    i = i + 1

grab = "Yes"
j = 0
inventory = []

print ("\nYou have found some items")

grab = input("\nDo you wish to pick them up? Yes/No")

if grab == "Yes":

    print("You have succesffuly picked up the items!")

    inventory = [" Knife "," Napkins "," A McDonald's Drinking Straw "," A Shoe Lace ", " Banana "]
print("\nThese are the items in your inventory:")

print(inventory)

if grab == "No":
    print("You are empty handed")

howMuch = len(inventory)
print("This is how many items are in your inventory:", howMuch)

while j < howMuch:
    print("\nThis is item:" + str(j) + inventory[j])
    j = j + 1

if inventory[0] == bag("Knife"):
    print("We have a match!")

if inventory[0] != bag( 0 ):
    print ("No like items")
```

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are instantiated with parentheses but they are indexed with square-brackets, just like lists. Using parentheses conveys "calling" a function with the name of your variable before the parentheses, but obviously that variable name is a tuple, not a function name. That is why you are being told your tuple is not callable, because it isn't, though your code is trying to call it.

Check your conditional (if) statements and change the parentheses to square-brackets. It's a common and understandable mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would have helped if my professor had covered that!

Comment: @JustinFarr You also can't use inventory[0] == bag["Knife"] but instead inventory[0] == bag[0] (I don't know it that was clear).

Comment: oh, yes, as @kren470 says, you can only index a tuple with an int, but if you want to index with a string you will need to create a dict, where the key is "knife" and you associate the returned object as the value (key-value pair). Not part of the original question, but definitely an error in the code.

Comment: I understand what you two are saying. I was just using trial and error and forgot to change it back to the original code. Thank you again!

Comment: This is wrong. Changing `inventory[0] == bag("Knife")` to `inventory[0] == bag["Knife"]` is still a syntax error. It's not a dict. And even if was a dict, using the term without spaces " Knife " wouldn't match.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you defined bag as a python tuple and accessed it with the wrong syntax.

Specifically you defined it like this:

```
bag = (" Knife ", " Gum ", " Water "," Bandages ", " Toilet Paper ")
```

And then you tried to access the first element of the tuple like this:

```
bag("Knife")
```

This is the syntax for a method or function call, so it is complaining that your tuple is not callable.

What you probably meant is

```
bag[0]
```

which will access the first item in your bag tuple.